# Existence of a model for $(X,L)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, arithmetic-geometry, line-bundles

Recently I was reading Moriwaki's work about the heights on arithmetic varieties, and I came across the following doubt about the setting.

Let $(X,L)$ be a couple where $X$ is a projective nonsingular algebraic variety over a number field $K$ and let $L$ a is line bundle on $X$. Then a model for $(X,L)$ is a couple $(\mathcal X,\mathcal L)$ such that $\mathcal X$ is a model over $O_K$ for $X$, and $\mathcal L$ is a $\mathbb Q$-line bundle on $\mathcal X $ such that $\mathcal L_{|K}\cong L$ (over $\mathbb Q$).

Now, I can  understand the existence and the construction of $\mathcal X$, but I have some problems about $\mathcal L$:

1. Why does such a $\mathbb Q$-line bundle exist?
2. Why do we have to appeal to  $\mathbb Q$-line bundles? I mean, why cannot $\mathcal L$ be just an ordinary line bundle on $\mathcal X$?

Essentially we are saying that there exists a line bundle $\mathcal M$ on $\mathcal X$ such that $\mathcal M_{|K}\cong n L$ for some natural number $n$. I am asking which such $\mathcal M$ exists and why it doesn't always exist with $n=1$.

Comment: It exists for $n=1$. Consider a Weil divisor $D$ with $O(D) = L$ and let $\mathcal{D}$ be the closure of $D$ in $\mathcal{X}$. Then $O(\mathcal{D})$ is a line bundle on $\mathcal{X}$ which extends $L$ (or: is a model for $L$). Probably, to explain why $\mathbb{Q}$-line bundles appear, Moriwaki wants a bit of more freedom when choosing the line bundle $\mathcal{L}$. (Also, small typo: "over $\mathbb{Q}$" should be "over $K$").